# Calculating the Dunford integral for a position and momentum operator from quantum physics

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, operator-theory

We have the Dunford integral which is useful to study  sectorial operators. The integral is given by

\begin{equation}
    f(A)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\Sigma}f(z)(z-A)^{-1}dz
\end{equation}

I would like to calculate it for $A=\hat{x}$, which is the position operator on some arbitrary function $f(z)$ where $f(z)$ is a bounded holomorphic function on a sector $\Sigma$ about the positive
real line containing the spectrum of A.

I am not sure how this is done, since $\hat{x}$ is real, while $f(z)$ is complex. I would also like to calculate the integral for $A=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, still the same problem arises.

I could though focus on the complex position operator $\hat{z}$ and  complex momentum operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ . But how is this integral solved then?

Solution to the position operator Dunford  integral:

We consider the position operator on the contour of the unit circle $\Sigma \leq1$ with $f(z)=e^{-z}$, with $||\hat{z}||\leq 1$

\begin{equation}
    f(\hat{z})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Sigma \leq1}\frac{e^{-z}}{(z-\hat{z}_0)}dz
\end{equation}

by residue theorem, the pole is at $\hat{z}_0$ and

\begin{equation}
    f(\hat{z})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Sigma \leq1}\frac{e^{-z}}{(z-\hat{z}_0)}dz=2\pi i\ Res(f;\hat{z})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    f(\hat{z})=\lim_{\hat{z}\rightarrow \hat{z}_0}(z-\hat{z})\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Sigma\leq1}\frac{e^{-z}}{(z-\hat{z}_0)}dz=- e^{-\hat{z}}
\end{equation}

But how to do this for an operator as $\partial/\partial\hat{z}$?

Comment: If you want to use a capital sigma, use `\Sigma`, not `\sum`.

Comment: You have a position operator $\hat{x}$. What space does the operator act on, and how is it defined on that space? For example, the free space position operator $M$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is multiplication by $x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, meaning that $Mf=xf(x)$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then $(\lambda I - M)^{-1}f = \frac{1}{\lambda -x}f(x)$.

Comment: Space is on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for the real position operator $\hat{x}$, since the position is independent of the wavefunction. The definition on that space would be  $[0,\infty]$ for the x dimension.